# How to make heavy json light?

Tags: node.js, json, encode, cryptojs

i want responsd a json file to web client from server. it is very heavy. and, user can post a json file. it is heavy too. (about, 50~150mb)

so, i have to find the way it make light.

then, i think that use encoding function.

i try use variety encode function, but it have to possible decode. but encode result is heavy too. it was differ to hash function.

```
obj_encoder: json => {
        const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ctr', 'key');
        let result = cipher.update(json, 'utf8', 'hex');
        result += cipher.final('hex');
        return result;
    }
```

therefore, i want know the encoding way able to decoding & encoded value's length is fixed.

or, if it is other good way, let me know please.

This problem has lasted more than a week. 
But I could not find a suitable way.

help me thank you.

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but have you considered the zlib compression module? https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html

Comment: I have never heard of that module before. Can I check the description and examples of the module?